# VB.net - If 1 then "Yes" if 0 then "no"

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have Database Software I am trying to make. The problem is I can't seem to find how to make this work, i'm new to this whole thing and have figured a lot out on my own but I can't seem to do this simple task?

I have a listView that displays the data from the SQl everything works great EXCEPT I need the dropdaown box the say yes or no but import into the SQL database a 1 or 0 and also in my list view i need it to display a Yes or a No instead of a 1 or a 0 ? Thanks IN Advance

Code:

```vb
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data

Public Class cmListAll
 Dim cn As New SqlConnection
 Dim cmd As SqlCommand
 Dim dr As SqlDataReader

 Private Sub frmReg_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    With Me.cboActive
        .Items.Add("Yes")
        .Items.Add("No")
        .SelectedIndex = 0
    End With
    Call connectMeToSQLServer("Data Source=Database;Initial Catalog=db_XXX;Integrated Security=False;Uid=sa; Pwd=PASS;")
    Call showList()
 End Sub

 Private Sub cboActive_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs)
    e.Handled = True
 End Sub

 Private Sub cboACTIVE_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Me.txtCredentials.Focus()
 End Sub

 Sub connectMeToSQLServer(ByVal cnString As String)
    Try
        With cn
            If .State = ConnectionState.Open Then .Close()
            .ConnectionString = cnString
            .Open()
        End With
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString)
    End Try
 End Sub

Function INC() As Boolean
    For Each t In Me.GroupBox2.Controls
        If TypeOf t Is TextBox Or TypeOf t Is ComboBox Then

        End If
        If t.Text = "" Then
            INC = True
        End If
    Next
End Function

Sub showList()
    cmd = New SqlCommand
    cmd.Connection = cn
    cmd.CommandText = "Select * from [Case Managers]"
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

    Me.ListView1.Items.Clear()
    While dr.Read
        With Me.ListView1
            .Items.Add(dr(0))
            With .Items(.Items.Count - 1).SubItems
                .Add(dr(1))
                .Add(dr(2))
                .Add(dr(3))
                .Add(dr(4))
            End With
        End With
    End While
    dr.Close()
End Sub

Sub clearMe()
    For Each t In Me.GroupBox2.Controls
        If TypeOf t Is TextBox Then
            If t.Text <> "" Then
                t.text = ""
            End If
            Me.cmdNew.Enabled = True
            Me.cmdSave.Text = "&Save"
            Me.cmdSave.Enabled = False
            Me.cmdDelete.Enabled = False
            Me.cboActive.SelectedIndex = 0
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub cmdNew_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdNew.Click
    For Each t In Me.GroupBox2.Controls
        If TypeOf t Is TextBox Then
            If t.Text <> "" Then
                t.text = ""
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Me.cmdNew.Enabled = False
    Me.cmdSave.Tag = "SAVE"
    Me.cmdSave.Text = "&Save"
    Me.cmdSave.Enabled = True
    Me.GroupBox2.Enabled = True
    Me.txtfirstname.Focus()
End Sub

Private Sub cmdSave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdSave.Click
    Select Case Me.cmdSave.Tag
        Case "SAVE"
            If INC() = True Then
                MsgBox("Please Complete All Fields!", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "")
                Exit Sub
            Else
                cmd = New SqlCommand
                cmd.CommandText = "Insert Into [Case Managers](Firstname,Lastname,Credentials,Active) Values('" & Me.txtfirstname.Text & "', '" & Me.txtlastname.Text & "', '" & Me.txtCredentials.Text & "', '" & Me.cboActive.Text & "' )"
                cmd.Connection = cn
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                MsgBox("Successfully Save!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "")
            End If
        Case Else
            cmd = New SqlCommand
            cmd.Connection = cn
            cmd.CommandText = "Update [Case Managers] Set firstname='" & Me.txtfirstname.Text & "', lastname='" & Me.txtlastname.Text & "', credentials='" & Me.txtCredentials.Text & "', active='" & Me.cboActive.Text & "' Where CaseMangerID = " & Me.ListView1.SelectedItems(0).Text & ""
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MsgBox("Successfully Updated!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "")
    End Select
    clearMe()
    showList()
End Sub

Private Sub ListView1_DoubleClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListView1.DoubleClick
    cmd = New SqlCommand
    cmd.Connection = cn
    cmd.CommandText = "Select * from [Case Managers] Where CaseMangerID = " & Me.ListView1.SelectedItems(0).Text & " "
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
    dr.Read()
    Me.txtfirstname.Text = dr(1)
    Me.txtlastname.Text = dr(2)
    Me.txtCredentials.Text = dr(3)
    Me.cboActive.Text = dr(4)
    dr.Close()
    Me.GroupBox2.Enabled = True
    Me.cmdSave.Enabled = True
    Me.cmdSave.Tag = "UPDATE"
    Me.cmdSave.Text = "&Update"
    Me.cmdDelete.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub cmdDelete_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdDelete.Click
    If MsgBox("Delete This Record?", MsgBoxStyle.Question + MsgBoxStyle.YesNo) = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
        cmd = New SqlCommand
        cmd.Connection = cn
        cmd.CommandText = "Delete from [Case Managers] Where CaseMangerID =" & Me.ListView1.SelectedItems(0).Text & " "
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MsgBox("Successfully Deleted!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "")
        Me.cmdDelete.Enabled = False
        Me.cmdSave.Enabled = False
        Call clearMe()
        Call showList()
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Don't use the Call keyword in vb.net. Also, don't use the sa user. Finally, several the sql statements are vulnerable to sql injection attacks. They're practically begging to get hacked.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You really should use parameters to send user-supplied information to the database.

Comment: Remove the unneeded code, just show where the problem is.

Comment: I don't know the unneeded code because i don't know where this stipulation would be included?

Comment: One way to solve your issue is that if you created the combobox with `No` as the first value, and `Yes` as the second one, in the line where you issue the `UPDATE`statement, rather then passing the `ComboBox.Text` value, you could pass the `ComboBox.SelectedIndex` (0 or 1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're looking at this line:

```
Me.cboActive.Text = dr(4)
```

? That's the only thing that looked to me like it might be displaying a yes/no field. You could just put a simple If/Else block there, but as there are several other significant flaws in how this code is structured, I thought it would be useful to re-write that whole method for you:

```vb
Private Sub ListView1_DoubleClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListView1.DoubleClick
    'Would be better to specify column names here
    Dim sql As String = "Select * from [Case Managers] Where CaseMangerID = @CaseManager"

    'Best practices in most cases call for creating a new connection object for each query
    Using cn As New SqlConnection("connection string here"), _
          cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, cn)

        'This is how to do string substitution in sql to protect against sql injection
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@CaseManager", SqlDbType.Int).Value = CInt(Me.ListView1.SelectedItems(0).Text)

        Using dr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            dr.Read()
            Me.txtfirstname.Text = dr(1)
            Me.txtlastname.Text = dr(2)
            Me.txtCredentials.Text = dr(3)
            Me.cboActive.Text = If(dr(4)=0,"No","Yes")
            dr.Close()
        End Using
    End Using 'No need to close the connection. The Using block takes care of it
    'The old code would have the left the connection open if an exception was thrown,'
    ' which could eventually lock you out of the database

    Me.GroupBox2.Enabled = True
    Me.cmdSave.Enabled = True
    Me.cmdSave.Tag = "UPDATE"
    Me.cmdSave.Text = "&Update"
    Me.cmdDelete.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

You'll need to do something similar later on to invert this for updates/inserts.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DisplayMember/ValueMember pair:

```
Dim dict As New Dictionary(Of Integer, String)
dict.Add(0, "No")
dict.Add(1, "Yes")

With Me.cboActive
    .DisplayMember = "Value"
    .ValueMember = "Key"
    .DataSource = dict.ToList()
    .SelectedIndex = 0
End With
```

Dictionary may not the best choice of class here, but works as a proof of concept.

Then just use `cboActive.SelectedValue` and pass that to the SQL query.